# Build.Gradle, Expecting an element

Tags: java, android

I use android studio with Java language. My problem is that, always when creating a new project, I get an error in build.gradle (: app)
I get "Expecting an element". This problem does not affect my application, it executes everything without problem, it only hinders me when you want to use Google Firebase. Thank you for reading!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDLh.png)

Comment: Instead of an image. Can you please post your `build` file code? So that we can copy & try to reproduce at our end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
api "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as answered if it helped you.